# download images dynamically with jquery in any container

Tags: jquery, asp.net

after searching google i got a code which works but this code download all the images at a time

### code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("table[id*=dgImages] img").each(function () {
          $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("original"));
          $(this).removeAttr("original");
      });
  });
</script>

<asp:DataList ID="dgImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" original='<%# Eval("photos")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

whatever the images are there in datalist the code download all at a time. so i need to customize it that only visible images should download and when user scroll down then next visible images should download.
so please guide me what to modify in my client script.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will ensure that only visible images are downloaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("table[id*=dgImages] img").each(function () {
    if($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() && $(this).offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {

      // callback on load complete          
      this.onload = function() { 
        alert('loaded'); 
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
      }

      $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("original"));
      $(this).removeAttr("original");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: can u help me bit more that when download complete of each image then i need to be notify by a function like callback. from that callback will do something......is it possible

Comment: this line actually download image $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("original"));
when each image download complete then i want to do something...so tell how can determine that one of image download complete. plzz help. thanks

Comment: thanks for ur help...need one more favour can i attach fade in effect like $(this).fadeIn('slow');
 when each image will be visible

Comment: fadeIn should ideally be given inside the load completion callback function. Like this: `$(this).fadeIn(speed)` where speed can 'fast', 'slow' etc.. Answer updated to demonstrate fadeIn.

Comment: here u add the code this.onload = function() { 
        alert('loaded'); 
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
      }
which notify when each image will download complete in client side. how to determine when all images in visible area will download complete.....so is there any trick. can i have any callback function for that....plzz help. thanks

Comment: Before setting the src attribute, you can set its visiblity to hidden `$(this).css('visibility', 'hidden')`. Once its loaded, instead of doing fadeIn, you can set it to visible `$(this).css('visibility', 'visible')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the appear plugin (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/) and add your function as an event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("table[id*=dgImages] img").each(function () {
          $(this).appear(function(){
             $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("original"));
             $(this).removeAttr("original");
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: can u help me bit more that when download complete of each image then i need to be notify by a function like callback. from that callback will do something......is it possible

Comment: this line actually download image $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("original"));
when each image download complete then i want to do something...so tell how can determine that one of image download complete. plzz help. thanks

Comment: You can bind to the load event of the image $(this).bind("load", function(){/*do stuff*/}); where "this" is assumed to be a reference to your image. More info on this method can be found here: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/image-onload-isnt-being-called

Comment: thanks for ur help...need one more favour can i attach fade in effect like $(this).fadeIn('slow');
 when each image will be visible

Comment: how to determine when all images in visible area will download complete.....so is there any trick. can i have any callback function for that....plzz help. thanks